# Need help building sql query

Tags: sql

select max(case when field_number = 7 then value end) value from wp_rg_lead_detail group by lead_id having max(case when field_number = 21 then value end) > curdate()I already tried my best reading documentation and searching on Google but i can't figure it out..

[image]

I need to build a query where it selects the value of field_number 7 if field_number 19 has the value 1 and the date of field_number 21 is past the current date.

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE field_number IN (7, 19) AND value = 1
```

But that only gives me the row where field_number is 19

**EDIT:**
I need to get the value of field_number 7 where field_number 19 is past the current date. There can be multiple inctances where field_number is 7 (each lead_id is a different "person" of which i need the field_number 7 value) Where field_number 22 has the value 1 is no longer applicable

**EDIT2:**
Hey guys thanks! With your help the problem is now solved. The code that i'm using now is (thank you sgeddes):

```
SELECT value FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE field_number = 7 AND EXISTS (SELECT field_number, value FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE field_number = 21 AND value > CURDATE())
```

Comment: Is the unique key here via lead_id and form_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `group by` with `max` and `case`.  I'm assuming the unique group is `lead_id` and `form_id`:

```
select max(case when field_number = 7 then value end) value
from wp_rg_lead_detail
group by lead_id, form_id
having max(case when field_number = 19 then value end) = 1 
    and max(case when field_number = 21 then value end) > curdate()
```

The last part depends a little on which database you are using (curdate is mysql, getdate() is sql server), but this should give you the general idea.  You may need to cast the value to a date as well.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74326/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT o.value
FROM wp_rg_lead_detail o
JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail t1
    ON t1.lead_id = o.lead_id
    AND t1.form_id = o.form_id
    AND t1.field_number = 19
    AND t1.value = 1
JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail t2
    ON t2.lead_id = o.lead_id
    AND t2.form_id = o.form_Id
    AND t2.field_number = 21
    AND t2.value > CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
WHERE o.field_number = 7
```

- It selects the value from your table;
- Joins it on itself, where the field number is 19 and its value is 1;
- Performs the same join where the field number is 21 and the date is past today;
- Inner joins will limit this to show the relevant details only.

**Edit**
Thanks Hans for the reminder that I forgot the Where clause :)

Comment: I think you need to add a 'where field_number = 7' to get the right row. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: Thank you for the big help! Only line I can't get to work is " AND t2.value > CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)" this gives me the following error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GetDate(),126) WHERE o.field_number = 7 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 12

Comment: Oh yes, it should be curdate() in mysql. You might have to convert it to match the format of your column

Comment: Yes it works when I change it to curdate()! Only problem now is that it only returns one row while there have to be several (there are multiple instances, each lead_id is a different "person")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
WHERE EXISTS ( subquery );
```

Conditional

For example(As i understand):

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_rg_lead_detail 
WHERE field_number IN (7,19) 
AND EXISTS (
           SELECT * 
           FROM wp_rg_lead_detail
           WHERE field_number = 19 AND value = 1)
```